# Не запускается учебный проект на Django 1.10.2

Tags: django

Выполняю [проект](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/), который рассматривается в официальной документации Django. Работает приложение polls, запускается админка, а переход на главную страницу выдаёт следующее:

[image: Скриншот 01]

Структура файлов:

```
firstsite/
    firstsite/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
    polls/
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        apps.py
        migrations/
            __init__.py
        models.py
        tests.py
        urls.py
        views.py
    static/
    manage.py
```

Часть содержимого ./firstsite/**settings.py**:

```
...
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'polls',
]
```

Содержимое ./firstsite/**urls.py**:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
]
```

Содержимое ./polls/**urls.py**:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Содержимое ./polls/**views.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, World!")
```

**Конфиг сервера:** *Ubuntu 16.04.1, Virtualenv 15.0.1, Virtualenvwrapper 4.3.1-2, Python 3.5.2, Django 1.10.2, Postgre 9.5+173, uWSGI 2.0.12-5, Nginx 1.10.*

Как видно из питоновских модулей — всё один в один с туториала, а не работает. Я в тупике, так как начал изучать фреймворк недавно и пока только разбираюсь с принципами. Очень прошу помощи!

Comment: Я так понял, по этому туториалу главная и не должна работать

Comment: Про принципы: ссылки прописываются в `urls.py` в `urlpatterns`, и главной страницы там сейчас нет, пропишите (не забыв создать view) — появится

Comment: Кстати, [есть перевод на русский](http://djbook.ru/rel1.9/intro/tutorial01.html) (там для версии 1.9, но разницы почти никакой)

Comment: Как же так?.. Вы меня в тупик поставили )) Ведь до добавления приложения polls главная работала. И не надо было её в urls прописывать. Ну то есть, из коробки только созданное приложение работает же, и ничего, кроме admin, в urls не прописывалось. Не понимаю...

Comment: Из коробки работала главная страница по умолчанию, которая есть только когда в urls как раз ничего не прописано :)

Comment: andreymal, спасибо за подсказку, я видел этот сайт, но как-то с новой версией решил использовать новый оригинальный туториал.

Comment: Ну и, для полноты картинки, не подскажете, как главную прописать вместе с view? Буду премного благодарен.

Comment: Ну в первом ответе минимальный рабочий вариант уже предложили, я вернусь — попробую подробнее про принципы прописать

Comment: Спасибо! Очень бы хотелось почитать про принципы, а то в первом ответе не понятно почему это рабочий вариант.

Answer (score 1):

```
    from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('polls.urls')),
]
```

это самый минимальный рабочий вариант, обычно многие ребята для главной страницы создают отдельное приложение скажем Frontend

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
    from django.contrib import admin

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
        url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
        url(r'^', include('frontend.urls')),
    ]
```

и вьюшка

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def main_page(request):
    return render('name_of_html.html', {})
```

url

```
from django.urls import url
from app_name import views


urlpattenrs = [
       url(r'^$', views.main_page, name='main_page')
    ]
```

Comment: Спасибо! А не подскажите, зачем в официальном туториале пишут нерабочие варианты кода? Или я чего-то недопонимаю?

Comment: там рабочий вариант, но в туторияле они имели ввиду не главную страницу, а страницу приложение.
На вашем примере что б зайти на ваше приложение ссылка будет такой
http:// 0.0.0.0:8000/polls/

Comment: Вау! Терпеть не могу этого междометия, но в данном случае, именно «Вау!» Не ожидал увидеть такой отзывчивости. Спасибо Вам огромное! Про ссылку на приложение polls я знаю, ведь писал же, что открывается всё, кроме главной страницы. Ещё раз спасибо, а впереди второй шаг туториала ))

Comment: А вообще, я, почему-то думал, что приложение в директории /firstsite/firstsite и есть главная страница. И ссылку на неё Django формирует автоматически.

Comment: То ли я тупой, то ли лыжи не едут... Сейчас такая же картинка, как на скриншоте в начале поста, но с добавлением строчки: 3. ^/

Comment: И админка перестала работать: «ImproperlyConfigured at /admin/
The included URLconf '<module 'frontend.urls' from './frontend/urls.py'>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.»

Comment: вы не правильно импортировали url или не правильно прописали его. можете скинуть главную url и url приложение

Answer (score 1):

Суть такова:

- сайт на Django — это кучка собранных вместе отдельных приложений (apps)
- приложения должны быть как можно более самодостаточны и независимы друг от друга; в идеале их должно быть возможно перенести по отдельности на совсем другие сайты без изменений (хотя нужно заметить, что это не всегда возможно)
- есть некий файлик с настройками, с которого начинается загрузка всего сайта. Стоит заметить, что он необязательно должен называться `settings.py` и вообще необязательно должен находиться внутри проекта
- в этом файлике с настройками в `INSTALLED_APPS` прописывается эта самая кучка собираемых вместе приложений
- а в `ROOT_URLCONF` — файлик (обычно `чтототам/urls.py`, точнее в формате Python-модуля `чтототам.urls`, но тоже необязательно), привязывающий ссылки к вьюхам этих собранных в кучку приложений

Вот в вашем случае:

- такое отдельное приложение пока одно — `polls`
- `polls` пока что ни от кого кроме собственно джанги не зависит, и его можно спокойно перенести на другой сайт, если приспичит
- файлик с настройками — `firstsite/settings.py`, и его использование по умолчанию прописано в файле `manage.py` вот в таком виде:

  ```
  os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "firstsite.settings")
  ```

  его можно поменять на сторонний файлик, переопределив переменную окружения `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` (и это однажды придётся делать), но это уже совсем другая история
- приложение `polls` прописано в `INSTALLED_APPS`, что запускает всякую тёмную магию с моделями и админкой, которые автоматически подхватываются джангой (обратите внимание, что `firstsite` там не прописан и как django-приложение он сейчас не используется)
- внутри настроек прописан `ROOT_URLCONF = 'firstsite.urls'`, и уже в файле `firstsite/urls.py` прописано подключение ссылок с `polls/urls.py`

И вот в вашем `firstsite/urls.py` прописано подключить все ссылки, которые прописаны в модуле `polls.urls` (файлик `polls/urls.py`) и ко всем ним добавить в начало `polls/`. В итоге получается, что `http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/` есть, а `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` никто не прописал и его нету.

Есть несколько способов прописать это:

- банально убрать префикс `polls/`, тогда главной страницей сайта станет главная страница приложения `polls` (есть в соседнем ответе, повторяться не буду)
- создать новое приложение (например, `frontend`), и подключить его в `firstsite/urls.py` без префикса (тоже есть в соседнем ответе, повторяться не буду)
- скачать какое-нибудь стороннее django-приложение и подключить его главную страницу в качестве главной страницы сайта, но наверно это никому не надо :)
- поставить редирект куда-нибудь:

  ```
  from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView

  urlpatterns = [
      url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
      url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
      url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='index', permanent=False), name='site_index'),
  ]
  ```

  в такой конфигурации открытие `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` будет перенаправлять на `http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/`.

Кстати, насчёт `pattern_name='index'`: этот `'index'` у вас прописан в файлике `polls/urls.py`, это имя однозначно идентифицирует шаблон ссылок, к которому она привязана, и по этому имени нужно будет ссылаться на главную опросов с любого места сайта (в частности, для этого самого редиректа в примере выше). Однако, когда приложений будет много, то почти у всех них будут какие-то свои главные страницы (список постов блога, список товаров магазина, форма обратной связи и т.п., если делать это всё отдельными приложениями), и если им всем прописывать имя `index`, то будет конфликт. Поэтому лучше исправить `'index'` на, например, `'polls_index'`, что однозначно будет указывать на главную страницу именно приложения `polls`. Хотя в рамках туториала это не столь важно.

Comment: Как-то получилось сумбурнее чем хотелось

Comment: Спасибо Вам, мил человек! Сейчас попробую сделать главную страницу отдельным приложением, руководствуясь Вашим замечанием и кодом ilgiz kasymov.